# in python pandas how to get value of dynamic series/ column data transformation

Tags: python, pandas, series

I am trying to merge two csv and transforming the values in one csv by looking up constant values in another csv.i am able to get series but but not able to get the correct cell value. Can you please suggest?
I am calling the below function in reading the main csv and transforming the language column

```
dataDF['language'] = 
dataDF['language'].apply(translateLanguagetest)

def translateLanguagetest( keystring):
    print("keystring" + keystring)
    ref_Data_File = Path('C:\sampletest')/ "constant.csv"
    refDataDF = pd.read_csv(ref_Data_File)
    refDataDF['refKey']=refDataDF['sourcedomain']+"#"+refDataDF['value']
    +"#"+refDataDF['targetdomain']
    refDataDF['refValue']=refDataDF['target']
    modRef= refDataDF['refValue'].where(refDataDF['refKey']== 
    'languageSRC#'+keystring+'#languagetarget')
    print("modRef: "+modRef )
    cleanedRef = modRef.dropna()
    f(cleanedRef)
    print(cleanedRef)
    value = cleanedRef.loc[('refValue')]
    return value
```

The contents of constant.csv is 
    value,sourcedomain,targetdomain,target
    ita,languageSRC,languagetarget,it
    eng,languageSRC,languagetarget,en

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution and it was a simple one. Being new to python, took some time to find the answer. I am reading the constants csv before and passing the constants dataframe as parameter to the method for transformation of column value.

```
     import unittest
     from pathlib import Path
     import pandas as pd
     class AdvancedTestSuite(unittest.TestCase):
          """Advanced test cases."""

         def test_transformation(self):

             data_File = Path('C:\Test_python\stackflow')/ "data.csv" 
             data_mod_File = Path('C:\Test_python\stackflow')/ "data_mod.csv" 
             dataDF = pd.read_csv(data_File)
             ref_Data_File = Path('C:\Test_python\stackflow')/ "constant.csv"
             refDataDF = pd.read_csv(ref_Data_File)

             refDataDF['refKey']=refDataDF['sourcedomain'] \
                 +"#"+refDataDF['value']+"#"+refDataDF['targetdomain']
             refDataDF['refValue']=refDataDF['target']
             dataDF['language'] = dataDF['language'].apply(
                lambda x: translateLanguagetest(x, refDataDF))
             dataDF['gender'] = dataDF['gender'].apply(
                 lambda x: translateGendertest(x, refDataDF))
             dataDF.to_csv(data_mod_File,index=False)
     def translateLanguagetest( keystring, refDataDF):
         print("keystring" + keystring)
         modRef= refDataDF['refValue'].where(refDataDF['refKey']== 
             'languageSRC#'+keystring+'#languagetarget')
         #removes the NaN number. modRef is an numpy.ndarray. 
         cleanedRef = modRef.dropna()  
         #after ckeab up,since only one row is remaining, item to select the value 
         #with one element
         value = cleanedRef.item()
         return value
     def translateGendertest( keystring, refDataDF):
         print("keystring" + keystring)
         modRef= refDataDF['refValue'].where(refDataDF['refKey']== 
             'genderSRC#'+keystring+'#gendertarget')
         #removes the NaN number modRef is an numpy.ndarray. 
         cleanedRef = modRef.dropna()
        #after ckeab up,since only one row is remaining, item to select the value 
        value = cleanedRef.item()
        return value

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest.main()

    The data.csv before transformation
    Id,language,gender
    1,ita,male
    2,eng,female
    The constant.csv
    value,sourcedomain,targetdomain,target
    ita,languageSRC,languagetarget,it
    eng,languageSRC,languagetarget,en
    male,genderSRC,gendertarget,Male
    female,genderSRC,gendertarget,Female
    The csv after transformation:
    Id,language,gender
    1,it,Male
    2,en,Female
```